# Does systemd have a specifier for the Working Directory

Tags: systemd

When I specify a working direcotry in a unit file I would like to refer to it from the ExecStart section via a specifier i.e.

```
[Unit]
Description=A test daemon that says hello
[Service]
Type=oneshot
WorkingDirectory=/home/foo/scipts
ExecStart="%<<WORKING_DIRECTORY_SPECIFIER>>/echo_hello.sh"
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

Is this possible with Systemd and if it is not are there any work-arounds?

Comment: For ExecStart you *should* still be using full paths, not 'relative' paths or substitution.  Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can use `~` or an absolute directory path. Careful though: `~` is likely to point to `/root/` as the home of the user of the unit.

and WorkingDirectory itself understands [specifiers](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers) but those are not user specific except for

```
"%g"    User group  
"%G"    User GID    
"%u"    User name   
"%U"    User UID
```

but those tend to default to user root.

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to specify specifically the Working Directory in the `ExecStart`, since all commands will be launched as if you have already specified it. Thats the point of it.

You should NOT use `~`, since this will use the `$HOME` of the `$USER` as which the service is running as. Instead, use relative paths.

If your `WorkingDirectory` is pointing to `/home/foo/scripts/`, then you just need to use `ExecStart=./somescript.sh`
If you have subdirectories, its the same thing - `ExecStart=subdir1/subdir2/somescript.sh`.
`WorkingDirectory` is basically a `cd` for the services.